# How to add tax to PayPal Installment Button

Tags: html, paypal, tax

I have a business PayPal account.  I have added an installment button for a product on my website. On checkout, the tax is not calculated or added to total.  My tax table in PayPal is correct.  I notice that the Buy Now buttons have tax instructions when you create them but the Installment Button does not. 
I searched the Questions already asked and thought I found the answer by adding the following code to the button html. It didn't work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="5">
```

How do I add the 5% tax to Payment 1 and to Payment 2 and it shows on the checkout and the invoice?
I have a limited understanding of html and I am hoping it is something simple.

Comment: Oops...this is the code I tried.  Didn't show up in my question.          <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="5">

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add tax as a separate line item as Installment Plans accept only one "amount" to spread out over the installment time. You can add tax and shipping to the total amount you are going to charge, though. However, it will not show as a "tax" line on the invoice.